# html text input broken - Nexus-S 4G / Android 4

Tags: android, html, input, nexus-s

I'm getting an odd issue in one specific scenario, wondering if anyone had seen similar or had any ideas.

```
<form action="myurl" method="post" id="login">
    <label for="userId" class="text-large">Username</label>
    <input id="userId" type="text" maxlength="15" required="1" />
    <label for="accessCode" class="text-large">Access Code</label>
    <input id="accessCode" type="password" maxlength="4" required="1" />
</form>
```

I thought at first it was the `maxlength`, as it would not let me modify the field once I got to the max length. However, it's stopped letting me type altogether, no registering anything I type in the field. The keyboard still pops up, and the intelitype/autocomplete above the keyboard registers typing, but nothing shows in the input.

I don't think there's anything fancy happening in the css, no strange hiding or anything, just an input field with a border.

I tried disabling our javascript validation, no change.

I tried removing the maxlength attributes from all fields, no change.

It appears to be specific to this one device type. Testing with Galaxy SII/SIII or any other android OS phone does not have this result.

Comment: I don't have these devices to test or to really know the answer, but you could try to do your own maxlength check with javascript.  Add an onkeypress event to each input that requires a max length, and if the text box is at its maximum length return false disabling the ability to add more text.  (Be careful though, you will need to check for keypress type, otherwise you could prevent them from even doing a backspace!

Comment: @crowebird even without any javascript or maxlength attribute, I'm still not able to type in input fields.

Comment: Well that is strange, thought maybe there was a maxlength bug.  Has it stopped working with any form input on any page, or just your own?

Comment: @crowebird Any on all. Clearing cache and history didn't do anything. Closing out of ALL browser windows and restarting the browser allows me to type again, however, issue starts when I hit that max length in a field. Looks like a device-specific bug.

Comment: Idk if is related to this. But there's a strange behavior on inputs fields on Android's browser prior to 4.3 when their have the -webkit-users-select: none; property.
Basically, you're not able to enter any text on _SOME_ of them.
It's fixed on Android 4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, finally!

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35264

This is a known issue. The only workaround is to create a javascript validator that removes all maxlength attributes from fields.